# Appending .00 after the number column while masking sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to append `.00` at the end of the column value. Suppose the value of the column is `3`, it should be displayed as `3.00`.

I tried using below:

```
SELECT cast(field_name as decimal(12,2))
  FROM table_name 
 WHERE field_name <> 0
```

but this didn't return in the required format.

field type:-Number(9,2)

Comment: use a proper format to display the floating numbers

Comment: Something like `cast(column-name as decimal(12,2))`. Or fix it in the display layer...

Comment: this didnt work in my case...how to fix in the display level?

Comment: Sorry, typo, meant layer. I mean return an integer, and have the display function to print it formatted as you prefer.

Comment: What is the data type of `field_name`?

Comment: As you only need this for _display_ purposes: Either use `to_char()` or let your application do the formatting.

Comment: i need the result in the number format only.

Comment: @Ankitbatra, what is it about a string like `3.00` that makes you think it's not in a number format? You need to be clear about whether you're worried about how the value is *stored* vs. whether you're trying to *display* it in a particular format.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to print a result, treating your number as a string, you can convert it to `varchar`, with the appropriate format mask:

```
SELECT to_char(field_name, 'fm999999999.00')
```

Comment: no i will be needing the result in the number format only

Comment: It's not that clear to me; if you need a way to display a number, to_char is the right way; otherwise, a number in Oracle has no display format; so, no matter the type of your number column, you will always need to use a char conversion to control the display format.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming your value is an integer..

```
SELECT CAST(Integer_Column AS DECIMAL(12, 2))
```

Please be aware, if you intend to allow the updating / creating of values like this, they should be saved in a `DECIMAL` column, saving them in an `INT` column will lose your data after the decimal point.

Thanks to JarlH for the note on integer length.

Comment: An integer can be up to 10 digits. DECIMAL(12, 2) is safer.